# Laravel strange behavior with eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I know that this question may be duplicated, but no current solution helped me to figure out the problem !
I have 2 models: User and Account, where user can have multiple accounts, but an account should belong to only one user.
Here the relations in the models:
In User:

```
class User extends Model {
  public $table = 'users';
  public function accounts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Account::class, 'user_id');
  }
}
```

In Account:

```
class Account extends Model {
  public $table = 'accounts';
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
  }
}
```

For table structure:
User: (id,name,email,password)
Account: (id,user_id,points)

When I do `User::find(1)` it returns null, despite I have a user in my database with the id 1.
The same Problem when I do `Account::find(1)->user` it returns null, but `Account::find(1)` works fine.
Any solution?

Comment: add full code of User.php

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: add your user table structure and user model code both

Comment: @J.Doe see updates

Comment: for the others, I updated my question and I added the structure.

Comment: @Moses this method is very simple, may be problem in db, need more info

Comment: In db I have 2 rows:
1 row in users with the id, and the same for accounts table

Comment: have you tried commenting off the relationships methods then call `User::find(1)` once again . (?)

Comment: I fixed It !! the problem was because the "deleted_at" column of this user is not null !!